# D3 Zoom+Drag Flickering

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am trying to use the zoom+drag feature in D3 from this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

I would like to mimic a zoom+drag image cropping using svg and d3. However when I drag it seems to flicker much, and now sure what to do to make it smoother. Also, how can I keep it within the black rectangles boundary?

Link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gaqay/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: For the flickering, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674872/d3-force-layout-making-pan-on-drag-zoom-smoother) -- http://jsbin.com/kasojoki/1/edit

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks for this! But how can I allow the dragging only when moused over the image?

Comment: You could check the current mouse position and ignore the drag if not over the image.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same problem. When I search for the answer, I saw yours. I managed to resolve mine though I have not had a logic answer yet. So I wish any guru out there can explain for us.

Basically I have no problem when I follow this tutorial:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999

```
 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
  .append("g");
```

Then I realize that the last without the last `.append("g")` it sill works, so I delete this line only after a while later I notice the problem. (Take me a while to checking local history).

But to answer you question, you may want to try have one "g" for zoom, and another "g" inside for all the drawings.